# Show different data from 3 columns in one column but in separated rows

Tags: crystal-reports, report

i have some troubles with this situation in Crystal Reports, i have 3 columns with diferent data in each one, but i want to show them in one column but in different rows, i think is like an union equivalent in SQL, but im not sure, i have tried with an if but it doesn't work, heres an example that what i want to do:

My 3 columns if i put them separated, they display like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUGAi.png)

and i want to show them like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBMqs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a formula field with a formula like this

```
If Not IsNull({Data1}) Then {Data1}
Else If Not IsNull({Data2}) Then {Data2}
Else If Not IsNull({Data3}) Then {Data3}
```

(Values in square brackets are placeholders for your columns, you can add them in formula workshop dialog.)

Then place the new formula field into the report.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! i was doing it the wrong way i gues... i was doing:                                  If {Data1} = {Data1} Then {Data1}                                                                                                                                                                                 Else if {Data2} = {Data2} Then {Data2} etc... but thank you so much for you answer, it worked perfectly!